# How do I make these models work with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model

A long time ago I started working on a simple project to learn a bit more about ASP.NET. A bit later I decided to use a database for storage instead of serialization, so I updated my existing models somewhat to try and make them work with Entity Framework code-first. Unfortunately, it seems that these classes are too complex to be converted to database tables.

[Here are the models](https://github.com/Reyth3/CommunityModels).

Take this part for example:

```
// Profile.cs
...
public virtual List<Profile> Friends { get; set; }
public virtual List<Community> Subscriptions { get; set; }
public virtual List<Community> Owned { get; set; }
```

I don't think this is going to work as it's supposed to, with multiple collections of entities of the same type referenced by another entity it's getting messy without a hierarchy-like structure of data.

How can I make these models more EF friendly?

Comment: Sure you can model this is a database. For instance, by giving the `Community` table two foreign keys to `Profile`.

Comment: @GertArnold Okay, how do I do that exactly? How do I connect al of them together in a C# class so that there are no complications?

Comment: I added this to my Community model:

    [ForeignKey("Owned")]
    public virtual Profile Owner { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Subscriptions")]
    public virtual List<Profile> Subscribers { get; set; }

This only throws more exceptions